# Retrofit parse selective JSON data

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am parsing JSON data from [this URL](https://jsonblob.com/c93d28fa-6ab6-11e7-a38a-550e296416a3). Calling like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Gift>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Gift>> call, Response<List<Gift>> response) {
            List<Gift> places = response.body();
    }
}
```

But I don't want this. I want to first check if the `flag` is `0`. If it is, then I want to get only the values of the `list` key. And want to use the following model:

```
class Gift extends RealmObject{
    String code, name;
    //getters & setters
}
```

How can I achieve this? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way sample

```
class GiftList{
String flag;
String flag1;
List<Gift> gifts;

}

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GiftList>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<GiftList>> call, Response<List<GiftList>> response) {
            List<GiftList> places = response.body();
      if(places.getFlag().equals("0"){
       List<Gift> gifts=places.getList();

    }
}
```

Comment: If my project contains many API calls than I need to create many classes like `GiftList` which I don't want.

Comment: if flag field is same for all the api calls then no need to take different classes you can have multiple instances in GiftList class it self.Or else you can use ResponseWrapper class

Answer (score 1):

You can create another POJO to store your `Gift` class, which store the outer value like `flag` and `flag1`, then you can access the `flag` to determine if you are going to go into `list`
here is how it looks like:

```
class GiftResponse extends RealmObject{
    int flag;
    String flag1;
    Gift[] list;
    //getters & setters
}
```

and keep your `Gift` class as it is, then you can get the data like:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<GiftResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<GiftResponse> call, Response<GiftResponse> response) {
            GiftResponse res = response.body();
            if(res.getFlag() == 0) {
                Gift[] arrGifts = res.getList();
            }
    }
}
```

ofcourse using this approach you change the call response type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ResponseWrapper class as below:

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {

  private T data;
  @JsonProperty("flag")
  public int flag;
  @JsonProperty("flag1")
  public String flag1;

  public T getData() {
     return data;
  }
}
```

And modify your `callback`

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseWrapper<List<Gift>>>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<ResponseWrapper<List<Gift>>> call, Response<ResponseWrapper<List<Gift>>> response) {
        int flag = response.body().flag;
        List<Gift> places = response.body().getData();
   }
}
```